# Is there a "do nothing" or "pass" statement in saltstack?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm looking for something equivalent to python's `pass` statement that can be used in a SaltStack state file.  As an example, I have inherited this:

```
include:
{% if grains['webserver'] == 'apache' %}
  - sls1
  - sls2
{% elif grains['webserver'] == 'nginx' %}
  - sls3
{% endif %}
```

Naturally, this will cause a Jinja exception if `grains['webserver']` doesn't get set. So one solution would be to set it explicitly in each state file I see this in, along the lines of

```
{%- set webserver = salt['grains.get']('webserver', 'Undefined') %}
```

But I'm hoping for something that I could append as an `else` clause to the effect of:

```
include:
{% if grains['webserver'] == 'apache' %}
  - sls1
  - sls2
{% elif grains['webserver'] == 'nginx' %}
  - sls3
{% else %}
  - pass, do_nothing, forget_me, Null, Empty, None, No_Way, Nope <=== What can go here?
{% endif %}
```

I understand that there are other ways of re-writing this logic, and am not asking how to solve this problem (as I already have).  But I'm explicitly looking for an equivalent of the `pass` statement in SaltStack.  Is there such a thing?

Comment: IMHO even if we manage to find an equivalent for `pass` in Saltstack, the `else` condition will not handle the situation where the `grain` is not set.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's the closest we're going to get.  Thanks, both.